# SceneKit imported .obj model physics body shape issue

Tags: swift, scenekit

I successfully imported .obj model to Xcode and converted it to .scn format. But when I try to add physics body shape, it appears on half of the model:

[image]

May be anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your object's geometry isn't centred around its origin. In the screenshot below can see that the box *is* centred around the origin but the mesh *is not*.

[image]

The way to solve this is to change the `Physics Shape` to `Default shape` and the `Type` to `Bounding Box` like so:

[image]

Now the physics shape is centred around the mesh:

[image]

Comment: Also, how to setup this programmatically?